# Glassfish or Tomcat+OpenEJB? Which variant is better for a small application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a small Java2EE application, which is planning to grow in time (not very soon). Now I'm trying to select the optimal free open-source production environment for it. I have two variants so far:

- GlassFish v3
- Tomcat + OpenEJB

The second variants looks more lightweight for me, moreover I use embedded OpenEJB for automated testing. What would you recommend for me? Am I going the right way?

Comment: Just a note that there are plans to Java EE 6 Web Profile certify the OpenEJB/Tomcat stack.  It should successfully grow with you.

Comment: @David Thanks, I already migrated to Tomcat/OpenEJB, with a big pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Tomcat+OpenEJB (with OpenJPA) is much easy-to-configure variant than GlassFish. Especially in a test-intensive project, like mine.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat + Spring. Just skip the EJBs. It will save you some development time, because you won't have to deploy your code to the app server in order to run tests.

Comment: I don't deploy my code to the AS in order to run tests, I use [embedded OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/embedded-configuration.html) (as I said in my question).

Comment: Guess I should have shown you more OpenEJB stuff at JavaOne a year or two ago instead of just having beers :)  Here's a demo if you're interested in the testing stuff  http://vimeo.com/6149008

Comment: Dave, I know about it and it is nice. :) However developer have to assemble the stack from pieces EJB implementation, JPA implementation, tx manager, jms, and other components of J2EE stack. Also, to me Spring has richer model for components and the life cycle, so there is no benefits of using EJB anymore.